# How to make a button like a drawer indicator(possible to put anywhere)

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to make a button like that, so it will animate when navigation drawer is start slipping.

[image]

How can I make a button like that? or how can I put drawer indicator anywhere I want(without action bar)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CircularFloatingActionMenu Library](https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu) for this purpose

Comment: i want to make a button alongside Pager Sliding Tab Strip. so it's not what i want :(

Comment: You can place button where ever you want and also, when navigation drawer start slipping, you can call click event of center button

Comment: seems like u misunderstand my case. I mean the bottom left button, not top right button :D

Comment: True. Marking\Highlighting the specific point in the image will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, my mistake :D